# I can't decide how to structure my table

Tags: sql, codeigniter, database-design

I'm building a website where basically there will be forms with multiple fields, to make user input really specific, instead of it all coming down in a single paragraph.

So I'm thinking maybe I'll put the data from the different fields of the form in different columns in the table.

Is that ok? That seems logical but I want to wrap up the form data (with many different field inputs that need to stay separated and not mixed) and then put it in the table in a single column, and thus, the table would consist of only the bundled information from the form, and a unique post ID associated with that particular form data bundle.

And when I've to show the information from the different fields of the form in a page, I'd get the form data bundle from the database, and somehow split it back into its original constituents, and display them under their respective headings as were when the form was being filled out.

How do I do that ?

I was thinking of passing the data into a special controller class which bundles the data collected from the form fields to an XML file. But then I don't know, maybe there would be too much unnecessary overhead of bundling and unbundling of the XML files?

I'm using CodeIgniter and MySQL.

EDIT - Example

I've a table `Interview`
Columns would be `ResumeID` `Name` `College Score` `Describe experience` `Familiarity with XYZ` `Describe yourself` and `Why you want this job`

Now except the first 3 columns, the rest could probably have around a few to 100s of sentences, that is, 20 to 500 or 1000 words even.

But this being an example, there are barely 6 fields. I'd have 18-20 form fields which would form columns in the table, and I'm thinking if it would be efficient enough to store all that long text in the database, or just wrap it up in some object and put the object along with the ID as -

`ResumeID` `RestOfTheInfo`

Thereby having only 2 columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store each field in the form in a separate column in the database table, with each form submission being a row.

This is how it's intended to work and is by far the simplest, best and most flexible solution. Don't make simple things complex unless you have no other choice. Packing and unpacking/parsing strings, storing XML in the database - all possible, but far too complicated for something simple like this - unless there's something that you're not telling us?

Anyway, basically, if your form looked like this:

```
Name* [               ]
Phone* [              ]
```

Then your table would look something like this:

```sql
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `form_submissions` (
  `submission_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `name` TEXT NOT NULL ,
  `phone` TEXT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`submission_id`) )
;
```

Keep it simple.

Comment: If your form looks completely different to that, or you think that this doesn't fit your scenario somehow, then if you add some examples to your question, and leave me a comment here, I'll update this answer.

Comment: There are like, 18 form elements that would hold data.. I was thinking that it would get dog tiring to manage so many columns

Comment: No - just have 18 columns - it'll be much worse trying to pack and unpack everything to strings. What sort of data are you collecting - stuff like name, phone number - that sort of thing?

Comment: data in every field might be at least a string of 20 words. Maximum 1000

Comment: The length of the data doesn't really matter - just use `TEXT` columns. Can you add an example to your question?